# Textmate: assigning language highlighting to files with some extensions

Tags: textmate

do you know if I can assign a specific highlighting to some files or extensions with textMate?

For example, I have a example.module file and I want to assign a php highlighting to it.

thanks

Comment: Notepad ++ has this built in and really easy to use.  I suggest converting.

Comment: @Daisetsu: Notepad++ is for Windows. TextMate is for Mac. That seems like a very bad suggestion.

Comment: @mipadi ahh, I didn't realize.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in the bottom status bar on TextMate, there is a list of languages. Select the one you want to use -- it'll apply to all files with the same file extension.

[image]